# Error when trying to update my stripe subscription schedule

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to make a subscription downgrade system. When the customer cancel the current plan, my app is supposed to downgrade him at the end of the current period. However, nothing works as expected, stripe throws me the following error :

```
type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  raw: {
    message: 'You can not update a phase that has already ended. Trying to update phase 0.',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
```

My code :

```
schedule = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({
          from_subscription: customer.subscription
        });
await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.update(schedule.id,{
        end_behavior: 'release',
        phases: [{
          start_date:subscription.current_period_start,
          end_date:subscription.current_period_end,
          items:current_items,
        },{
          start_date:subscription.current_period_end,
          items:newitms
        }],
      });
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I don't get the same error when I do a simple test using a normal active subscription in test mode. I'd suggest sharing full context of what the customer's current subscription is, what `status` it has at the time you call this code, and when that code gets called exactly